# Change display name of sender in mail when sender mail is coming from web config in C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, smtp

Below is my code for sending mail...

```
 public void SendBy(string to, string subject, string body)
{
    MailMessage nM = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();

    nM.To.Add("abc@compulynx.org");
    nM.Subject = subject;
    nM.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(oStream, Fname));
    nM.Body = body;
    System.Configuration.Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);
    System.Net.Configuration.MailSettingsSectionGroup settings = (System.Net.Configuration.MailSettingsSectionGroup)config.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings");

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(settings.Smtp.Network.Host);
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(settings.Smtp.Network.UserName, settings.Smtp.Network.Password);

    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.Send(nM);
}
```

and this is my web config code...

```
<system.net>
     <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="xyz@gmail.com" >
            <network host="smtp.gmail.com" 
                    defaultCredentials="false" userName="xyz@gmail.com" password="xyz"
                    port="587"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

this code is working fine but how i will change the sender display name,normally we use like this

```
 mM.From = new MailAddress("xyz@gmail.com","xyz");
```

but in my case I am not writing sender mail address any where , I am just getting from web config,then how I will change that name..i have current login user in my session,I want to display that name as a sender...

Comment: The "from" that is in your web.config isn't used as far as I can tell.  That configuration section is for configuring authentication on your SMTP server, and should have nothing to do with the actual message.  You can simply use the MailMessage.From property to set the display name like you showed in your last code snippet.

Answer (score 6):

should put it on smtp  from tag

```
<smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="XYZ&lt;xyz@gmail.com&gt;">
<network host="smtp.gmail.com" 
                defaultCredentials="false" userName="xyz@gmail.com" password="xyz"
                port="587"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set it like this in you web.config:

```
<network host="smtp.gmail.com" 
         defaultCredentials="false" 
         userName="&quot;xyz&quot;&lt;xyz@gmail.com&gt;"
         password="xyz" 
         port="587"/>
```

Refer the [supported formats for MailAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx).

Comment: Corrected. Needed some escaping